# How to resolve a null Scope_Indentity on cascaded insert?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, scope-identity

I'm performing a cascading insert in a SQL Server stored procedure. Then I pass the `SCOPE_IDENTITY` from the ID of the first table insert to the second table.

But during executing the stored procedure I get a NULL value for the `SCOPE_IDENTITY`:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Procedure InsertDDM_UserProfile, Line 43
>   Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Filter', table '.....dbo.DDM_Dashboard'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.

**Question**: why does the stored procedure return a null ID using `SCOPE_IDENTITY`?

This is the stored procedure I've drafted. FK constraints have already been set up for the tables:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDDM_UserProfile]
   @p_email VARCHAR(100),
   @p_dashboardName VARCHAR(100),
AS 
BEGIN    
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DDM_User] ([Email])
    VALUES (@p_email)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[DDM_Dashboard] ([Dashboard_Name], [DDM_USER_ID])
    VALUES (@p_dashboardName, SCOPE_IDENTITY())
END
```

And below are the two table's structure:

DDM_User-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DDM_User]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [varchar](80) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_DDMUser] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

DDM_Dashboard:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DDM_Dashboard]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Dashboard_Name] [varchar](100) NOT NULL,
    [DDM_USER_ID] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_DDMDashboard] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DDM_Dashboard] WITH NOCHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_DDMDashboard_DDMUser] 
        FOREIGN KEY([DDM_USER_ID]) REFERENCES [dbo].[DDM_User] ([ID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[DDM_Dashboard] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_DDMDashboard_DDMUser]
GO
```

Comment: Can we see the table schema of both tables? The Filter column on DDM_Dashboard is not allowing Null and it's not in your insert statement.

Comment: Sure I'll post that now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is nothing to do with `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`, during your second insert:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[DDM_Dashboard] ([Dashboard_Name], [DDM_USER_ID])
VALUES (@p_dashboardName, SCOPE_IDENTITY())
```

You are only inserting into two columns `[Dashboard_Name]`, and `[DDM_USER_ID]`. You do not specify a value for the column `[Filter]`, which from your error message does not allow null values, therefore your insert fails.

Comment: Hmm... You accepted this as an answer, but I don't see the `[Filter]` column in your table schema.

Comment: Yes the filter column was actually still in the table. An earlier drop of this column didn't complete meaning this ghost column was still in the table schema.

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @Value1 varchar(50) = 'Test1', @Value2 varchar(50) = 'Test2';

DECLARE @Table1 table (Id int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1), Value varchar(50) NOT NULL);
DECLARE @Table2 table (Id int NOT NULL, Value varchar(50) NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO @Table1 (Value1)
OUTPUT inserted.Id, @Value2 INTO @Table2 (Id, Value)
Values (@Value1)
;

SELECT * FROM @Table1;
SELECT * FROM @Table1;
```

edit:
As GarethD pointed out, this is not actually a valid solution to your problem due to the foreign key constraint. However in other scenarios this is a useful way to handle cascading inserts and updates as it is an atomic operation of both records.

Comment: A little explanation would help this. Although I think I know what you are getting at, unfortunately in this case you could not insert to the second table directly using the `OUTPUT` clause because of the foreign key relationship, and with just a single row insert it would be more complicated to use `OUTPUT` with a temporary table instead of just `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. If there were no foreign key, or inserting multiple rows, then this would definitely be the way forward.